# Code to simulate a segfault

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I’m trying to simulate a segfault so I can see some of the conditions that would happen when one exists for debugging a much more complex script that is segfaulting. The code is run via CLI (cron).

Since this app is written in PHP, does anyone have code that will cause a segfault in PHP?
The servers are using PHP 5.3, but I’m running 5.5 and 5.6 on two other servers, so code that creates a segfault in any version would work.

Comment: get your php script's PID, then  `kill -11 $pid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as @Marc B says in comment

```
kill -11 $pid
```

or

```
kill -SIGSEGV $pid
```

where `$pid` is the pid of the interpreter running your script. Any script would do, one convenient possibility would be just `sleep(60)`, which gives you 60 seconds to send it a SIGSEGV before it exits cleanly on its own.